# Navigation Bar on top when rotating

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have UIViewController (for example, loginVC) and I'm trying to add it's view on top of all views.

I tried to add this view to `AppDelegate`

```
[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].window addSubview:loginVC.view];
```

But in this case autorotation doesn't work, so I tried to add this view to `NavigationController`'s view. NavigationController is rootViewController:

```
[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].navigationController.view addSubview:loginVC.view];
```

It looks good and autorotating, but it has strange behavior when rotating.

After beginning of rotation, navigation bar is showing on top of loginVC.view and at the end of rotation is going behind this view, like it shown on screenshots (I've set red background to make it more visible, background is transparent, to see all stuff behind this view):

[image]
[image]
[image]

What I've tried:

- I found this somewhere on stackoverflow: disable UIView animations before rotating and enable them after rotating - doesn't look good, because rotating occurs without animation (it's a bit obvious)
- tried to make navigationBar hidden before rotation and make it visible after rotation, but in this case navigationBar bringing on top of loginVC.view

Next thing I gonna do - add this view on AppDelegate's window and handle rotation manually, but maybe there is some better way to do this?

**UPD:**

screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can see issue on second screenshot: navigation bar is on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend helped me with this problem

Here is the solution:

In AppDelegate I've created `UIWindow` property:

```
//AppDelegate.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *loginWindow;
```

Initialized it when application starts

```
//AppDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
....
    self.loginWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
    self.loginWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
    self.loginWindow.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.loginWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
....
    return YES;    
}
```

And then, in loginVC:

```
@interface loginVC ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIWindow *loginWindow;
@end

@implementation
....

- (void)show {
// setting up loginVC view 
    if (!self.loginWindow) {
          self.loginWindow = [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] loginWindow];
    }
    if (![self.loginWindow.rootViewController isEqual:self]) {
          [self.loginWindow setRootViewController:self];
    }
    self.loginWindow.hidden = NO;
//UPD:
    //[self.loginWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
//UPD2:
    [self.loginWindow makeKeyWindow];
}

- (void)hide {
// hiding view and stuff
    [[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] loginWindow] setHidden:YES];
//UPD:
    //[[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] window] makeKeyAndVisible];
//UPD2:
    [[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] window] makeKeyWindow];
}
@end
```

**UPD:**

No need to use `makeKeyAndVisible` method of UIWindow, second window will be always on top of first one.

**UPD2:**

Again updating my answer, maybe it will be useful for somebody.

Without `makeKeyAndVisible` I couldn't use `UITestField`s so I uncommented that code and faced another problem:

I have `UIViewController`, create an instance of another `UIViewController` inside this controller and call `[self presentViewController:...]`. In presented `UIViewController` I'm creating `loginVC`, but when I call

`[[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] window] makeKeyAndVisible];`

presented viewController disappears, but first view controller still has this controller as `presentedViewController`, so I can't present other view controllers.

My solution was change `makeKeyAndVisible` on `makeKeyWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

add your viewController in uinavigationcontroller and push uinavigationcontroller then always navigation bar is visible.

Comment: I've updated screenshots, as you can see, navigation bar is always visible, that's not the issue